# How to improve the performance of Crystal Reports with base64 images from FTP server?

Tags: sql-server, performance, ftp, crystal-reports, base64

Our website is linked to a SQL server where we store our customers' data. We also store our customers' images on an FTP server. When we need to generate some online reports, we have to fetch the images, convert them to base64 format, and display them using Crystal Reports. This process takes a lot of time. For example, for 2000 records, it takes about 5-10 minutes to generate the reports and another 5-10 minutes to export them as excel/pdf files.

Do you have any suggestions on how to improve the performance of this report and the export process?